# RegEx: If first character is '%' or alphanumeric then

Tags: node.js, regex

in nodejs, I have to following pattern

```
(/^(>|<|>=|<=|!=|%)?[a-z0-9 ]+?(%)*$/i
```

to match only alphanumeric strings, with optional suffix and prefix with some special characters. And its working just fine.

Now I want to match the last '%' only if the first character is alphanumeric (case insensitive) or also a %. Then its optionally allowed, otherwise it should not match.

Example:

**Should** match:

```
>test
!=test
<test
>=test
<=test
%test
test
%test%
test%
```

Example which should **not** match:

```
<test% <-- its now matching, which is not correct
<test< <-- its now **not** matching, which is correct
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a negative lookahead after `^` like

```js
/^(?![^a-z\d%].*%$)(?:[><]=?|!=|%)?[a-z\d ]+%*$/i
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WL6ny8/1/). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?![^a-z\d%].*%$)` - fail the match if there is a char other than alphanumeric or `%` at the start and `%` at the end
- `(?:[><]=?|!=|%)?` -  optionally match `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `!=` or `%`
- `[a-z\d ]+` - one or more alphanumeric or space chars
- `%*` - zero or more `%` chars
- `$` - end of string

Answer (score 2):

You might use an alternation `|` to match either one of the options.

```
^(?:[a-z0-9%](?:[a-z0-9 ]*%)?|(?:[<>]=?|!=|%)?[a-z0-9 ]+)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[a-z0-9%]` Match one of the listed in the character class
  - `(?:[a-z0-9 ]*%)?` Optionally match repeating 0+ times any of the character class followed by `%`
  - `|` Or
  - `(?:[<>]=?|!=|%)?` Optionally match one of the alternatives
  - `[a-z0-9 ]+` Match 1+ times any of the character class
- `)` Close non capture group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/M2Itna/1)

Comment: That regex would match also strings starting with a space, that for what I can understand is not in the requirement.

Comment: The pattern of the OP can also start with a space, but you can always rule that out in multiple ways `^(?! )(?:[a-z0-9 %]+|(?:[<>]=?|!=|%)?[a-z0-9 ]+)$`

Comment: Yes but the rule is "I want to match the last '%' only if the first character is alphanumeric"

Comment: @horcrux I see what you mean, I think the changed pattern will now be a better fit.